# Why won't this python web app page redirect me properly?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

I am trying to create a login page on python with flask and psycopg2 using a postgresql database and upon login it should redirect to a page or to registration if the login isn't found, but it won't redirect...
I have gotten the registration to work and store the username and password in the database. The end goal is to create a grocery store app with a registration and login feature. I have tried a few different ways to write this, but the page just won't redirect. I figure if the query wasn't working  it would at least take me to registration, but it just reopens the homepage... Please help.

the HTML for homepage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title> Homepage </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 Login or Register for your username and password (*required)<br>
  <form method="POST" >
    Login Information<br>
    Enter username*: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName", name="username" required><br> 
        Enter password*: <input type="text"class ="form-control" placeholder="Password", name="password",  type = "Password" required><br>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <a href = "/register" >Register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

the html for register page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title> You must create a username and password to login </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 Please input your information to register (*required)<br>
    <form method="POST" >
        Type in all fields below<br>
        Enter id*: <input type="text" placeholder="Customer ID" name="customer_id" required><br>
        Enter name*: <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name = "customer_name" required><br> 
        Enter balance*: <input type="text" placeholder="Type 0" name = "balance" required><br>
        Enter name*: <input type="text" placeholder="Type A12" name = "address_id" required><br>
        Enter username*: <input type="text" placeholder="UserName" name="username" required><br> 
        Enter password*: <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password" required><br> 
      
        
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

the python code

````
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request
from table_defs import * #ProductTable, Customer

app = Flask(__name__)

# conn and cur as global variables
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",
                            database="FreshCart",
                            user="postgres",
                            password="Alfred45"
                            )
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

# TODO: decide if it's ok not to close cursor or conn
# cur.close()
# conn.close()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.route('/product_search')
def product_search():
    return render_template('product_search.html', **locals())

@app.route('/product_search_response', methods=['POST'])
def product_search_response():
    # get form input
    sku = request.form.get("sku")
    description = request.form.get("description")
    category = request.form.get("category")

    #TODO: right now these queries are very brittle; consider what makes sense to add for ilikes and wildcards
    #TODO: distinguish between partial matches and exact matches?
    #TODO: make these safe queries like he talked about in class
    if sku:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE sku='{}'".format(sku))
    elif description:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE description='{}'".format(description))
    elif category:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE category='{}'".format(category))
    else:
        pass
        # TODO: do we need any action here?  If not, remove else block

    if cur.description != None:
        table = ProductTable(cur)
    else:                   # in the case of no cursor execution, gracefully return 'No Items' instead of crashing
        table = ProductTable({})

    return render_template('product_search.html', **locals())

@app.route('/add_product')
def add_product():
    return render_template('add_product.html', **locals())

@app.route('/add_product_response', methods=['POST'])
def add_product_response():
    # get form input
    sku = request.form.get("sku")
    description = request.form.get("description")
    category = request.form.get("category")
    size = request.form.get("size")
    abv = request.form.get("abv")
    calories = request.form.get("calories")
    fat = request.form.get("fat")
    carbohydrates = request.form.get("carbohydrates")
    protein = request.form.get("protein")

    # TODO: change response to execute product add and then display new record
    # TODO: add data validation checks if needed
    # TODO: add logic to check if the sku already exists and provide a link to the edit page
    # product_nutrition_alcohol_query =  "SELECT product.sku, description, category, product_size, \
    #         calories, fat, carbohydrates, protein, abv \
    #     FROM product \
    #         JOIN alcohol_content ON product.sku = alcohol_content.sku \
    #         JOIN nutrition_information ON product.sku = nutrition_information.sku \
    #     WHERE product.sku='{}'"

    #queries
    check_query = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE sku='{}'"
    product_insert_query = "INSERT INTO product (sku, description, category, product_size) \
            VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', {})"
    alcohol_insert_query = "INSERT INTO alcohol_content (abv, sku) \
            VALUES ({}, '{}')"
    nutrition_insert_query = "INSERT INTO nutrition_information (calories, fat, carbohydrates, protein, sku) \
            VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', {})"

    # insert into product if sku doesn't already exist
    cur.execute(check_query.format("product", sku))
    if cur.fetchone() == None:
        try:
            cur.execute(product_insert_query.format(sku, description, category, size))
            conn.commit()
            cur.execute(check_query.format("product", sku))
            prod_table = ProductTable(cur)
            prod_message = "Product added!"
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not insert into product")
            conn.rollback()
            prod_table = ProductTable({})
            prod_message = "Product could not be added"
#TODO: can't use same cursor for different things that need to be rendered - figure out a better way
        # insert into alcohol
        # if abv:
        #     try:
        #         cur.execute(alcohol_insert_query.format(abv, sku))
        #         conn.commit()
        #         cur.execute(check_query.format("alcohol_content", sku))
        #         alcohol_table = AlcoholTable(cur)
        #         alcohol_message = "alcohol information:"
        #     except Exception as e:
        #         print("Could not insert into alcohol_content")
        #         conn.rollback()
        #         # cur.execute(check_query.format("product", sku))
        #         alcohol_table = AlcoholTable({})
        #         alcohol_message = "Product could not be added"

        # insert into nutrition_information
        # if all([calories, fat, carbohydrates, protein]):
        #     pass    #add to nutrition query
        # elif any([calories, fat, carbohydrates, protein]) and not all(calories, fat, carbohydrates, protein):
        #     pass
    else:
        prod_table = ProductTable({})
        prod_message = "Product with this sku already exists; please try again"

    return render_template('add_product.html', **locals())

**#TODO: Create Login Page (we may have to create a registration page as well could serve to give User role ability to update schema/add new users)
        # pages run but code doesn't do what I want in db... 
        #   login page code  to check that login is valid - shakey, but just to get something started
        #   must create safe/prepared query for pw 
@app.route("/homepage", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])   
def homepage():
    return render_template("/homepage.html")
#TODO figure out why this wont redirect to another page once submit is hit
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])   
def checklogin():
    UN = request.form.get('username')
    PW = request.form.get('password')
   # query to check if the username exists from input
    query1 = "SELECT username, password FROM customer WHERE username = '{}' AND password = '{}'"
#check if login exists if not send user to registration
    rows = cur.execute(query1.format(UN, PW))   
    rows = rows.fetchall() 
    if len(rows)== 1:
        return redirect ("/") #once you login switch to current index/ product add/search
    else: 
        return redirect ("/register")
#TODO: Create a registration page which incorporates User Role to allow them to update data on Customer Schema           
@app.route("/register",  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registration():
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = request.form.get ('customer_id')
        name = request.form.get ('customer_name')
        balance = request.form.get('balance')
        address_id = request.form.get('address_id')
        dUN = request.form.get('username')
        dPW = request.form.get('password')
        query2 = "INSERT into customer (customer_id, customer_name, balance, address_id, username, password)  VALUES  ('{}', '{}', {}, '{}', '{}', '{}')"
        cur.execute(query2.format(id, name, balance, address_id, dUN, dPW))
        conn.commit()
        return redirect ("/homepage")
    return render_template("register.html", **locals())
           
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)** ```
````

Comment: is 'homepage' the target of the redirect if registration fails (homepage is the registration page)? and the HTML is saved in a file called "homepage.html" ? And whatever is at `/` is  the target of a successful login?

Comment: Why do you have a separate registration page if the homepage already prompts the user to register (or login) ? just have failed logins redirect back to the registration page since it is apparently doing both.

Comment: the target redirect is ("/") which is the index that will allow for other functionality and is the target of successful login. 

for unsuccessful login I want it to redirect automatically to register.html

Apologies if it seems I do not know a lot. I do not. I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to change the routes. I had two routes to the same place so instead of

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])   
def checklogin():
```

it should have been

```
@app.route("/checklogin", methods=['GET', 'POST'])   
def checklogin():
```

since the names were the same it was doing something weird where the query wasn't getting the data and instead it was just relaunching the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Your link points to an endpoint for which no route has been created. (you are using "/homepage" twice in the Flask app)

```
<a href = "/register" >Register</a>
```

You probably want

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])   
def checklogin():
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Let me edit the question. I didn't provide the entirety of my code. That did not work though.

Answer (score 0):

The QuickStart guide in the documentation shows redirect being used in conjunction with the url_for() function.

Like This:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

It's under "Redirects and Errors" here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Have you tried updating

```
return redirect ("/register")
```

to

```
return redirect(url_for('register'))
```

?